# "Not an answer" shouldn't be flagged?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I just noticed a strange reason for declining one of my flags (not an answer):

[image]

As a user without enough reputation to directly vote to close, I use flags instead.

Does this imply that I can't use any of the following flag reasons unless it is "to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"? I would've thought that the "in need of moderator intervention" flag would fall under that category, sure, but this seems wrong to me.

[image]

[This Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/249688/243324) suggests it's a common response for custom close vote reasons.

I don't have enough reputation to see who declined that flag, would someone who does mind sharing some more input?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue you raised is with a flag on an answer. Answers cannot be closed. Close vote reasons and reputation required to vote to close are not relevant.

You flagged an answer as "not an answer", suggesting that it doesn't attempt to answer the question. "Not an answer" flags may sometimes be processed by reviewers (with 2000 rep or more), but on smaller sites such as Magento, they are more likely to end up on a moderator's plate.

The moderator disagreed with your assessment of the answer. Indeed, it says in part

> I would suggest you either take a look a Zend Z-Ray, however a quick solution would be to integrate this extension to see what call is taking the longest: https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler
>
> If I had to guess what the issue is, something is deadlocking in the database.

While tentative, this does look like an attempt to answer the question.  If you consider this information to not be useful,  voting down is appropriate - and you have reputation for that.

There is another line in the answer:

> So I just tried it on a random demo site and it isn't increasing the site speed at all.

This shouldn't really be there: it's a commentary on another answer,  it's not even clear what "it" refers to, and the link is dead anyway. Editing this line out would be appropriate; this doesn't require a moderator, since everyone can suggest edits.

Comment: Very fair and rounded answer, thanks!

Comment: Editing an answer should be reserved to maintain the spirit of the answer, and this comment from the answerer sounds like they were going the extra mile to be helpful. I would leave it.

Comment: Loved your reasoning and I 100% agree with this.  But I don't think it is not appropriate to remove the last sentence. Because it clearly says he definitely tried out something to help OP. So better leave it.